# moving forward and backward between each month

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently am working on an application where I am attempting to create a calendar using javascript.  Based on the current date, I can select a back button and go back as many months as I would like and fetch the days within each month. I can also select a forward button and go forward as many months as I would like.  The issue I am running into is that if I go back to say October 2020, and hit the forward button, the calendar will start on January 2021 because I am cycling months based on the current date rather than the dates I am currently on. What I would like to achieve is if I am in October 2020 and hit the forward button, I like it to go to November 2020. Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

my code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [countTwo, setCountTwo] = useState(1);
  const [dates, setDates]=useState(null)

  const getDaysArray = async (s, e) => {
    let a = [];
    for (let d = new Date(s); d <= e; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
      a.push(new Date(d).toString());
    }

    return a;
  };

  const prevMonth = async () => {
    setCount((state) => state + 1);
    let d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - count);
    let firstDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1);
    let lastDay = new Date(firstDay.getFullYear(), firstDay.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);
    setDates(dates);
  };

  const nextMonth = async () => {
    setCountTwo((state) => state + 1);
    let d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + countTwo);

    let firstDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1);
    let lastDay = new Date(firstDay.getFullYear(), firstDay.getMonth() + 1, 0);

    const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);
    setDates(dates);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={prevMonth}>Prev Month</button>
      <button onClick={nextMonth}>Next Month</button>
      {dates &&
        dates.map((item, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{item}</div>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is a code pen for debugging! https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-brook-y2n7p?file=/src/App.js:0-1413

Comment: Instead of using `count` and `countTwo` to store the current month in the state, use a `Date()` object to store the current date.

Comment: could you possibly show how to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than tracking the current date, use a counter to keep track of the current month number. Then subtract or add one that that number for previous or next. And se the month using that number.

Here is a fork of your project with this solution:

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-rgb-mryst

And the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
   const [visibleMonth, setVisibleMonth] = useState(new Date().getMonth());
  //  const [countTwo, setCountTwo] = useState(1);
  const [dates, setDates] = useState(null);

  const getDaysArray = async (s, e) => {
    let a = [];
    for (let d = new Date(s); d <= e; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
      a.push(new Date(d).toString());
    }

    return a;
  };

  const prevMonth = async () => {
    let d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(visibleMonth - 1);
    setVisibleMonth((state) => visibleMonth - 1);
    let firstDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1);
    let lastDay = new Date(firstDay.getFullYear(), firstDay.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);
    setDates(dates);
  };

  const nextMonth = async () => {
    let d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(visibleMonth + 1);
    setVisibleMonth((state) => visibleMonth + 1);

    let firstDay = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1);
    let lastDay = new Date(firstDay.getFullYear(), firstDay.getMonth() + 1, 0);

    const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);
    setDates(dates);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={prevMonth}>Prev Month</button>
      <button onClick={nextMonth}>Next Month</button>
      {dates &&
        dates.map((item, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{item}</div>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: hey randy the code you sent appears to be the original code

Comment: This: "_The issue I am running into is that if I go back to say October 2020, and hit the forward button, the calendar will start on January 2021_" - does not occur in my fork. In my fork, this scenario produces November 2020. Please ensure you're looking at my fork.

Comment: ahh i see it now, the issue I'm noticing is that when i hit the previous button it starts at January 2020 and then goes to december 2019

Comment: I would like it to start at December 2020 and go to November 2020 and so on and so forth

Comment: the same issue appears when you hit the next button, it starts on march 2020

Comment: Yeah I forgot to set the starting point to the current date. - Try now as it has been updated.

Comment: Thank you my apologies I walked away from the computer for a couple minutes.  working with dates has been throwing me for a loop, so this is a big help

Comment: Glad to help! Have fun with this stuff.